# Relate and merge array of same Department

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application where I need to get combine the object of same department based on the 
conditions provided in the second Array and attach the relation to the object.

```
let inArr1 = [{"D1D2":"AND"},{"D3D4":"OR"}]
let inArr2 =[{"ID":"1","NAME":"KEN","DEPT1":"CSE"},
              {"ID":"2","NAME":"MARK","DEPT2":"IT"},
              {"ID":"3","NAME":"TOM","DEPT3":"ECE"},
              {"ID":"4","NAME":"SHIV","DEPT4":"LIB"},
              {"ID":"5","NAME":"TIM","DEPT5":"SEC"}
            ]
```

Output

```
 outArr ={ 
                 [{"ID":"1","NAME":"KEN","DEPT1":"CSE","REL":"AND"}, 
                  {"ID":"2","NAME":"MARK","DEPT2":"IT","REL":"AND"}], //Arr1
                 [{"ID":"3","NAME":"TOM","DEPT3":"ECE","REL":"OR"}, 
                  {"ID":"4","NAME":"SHIV","DEPT4":"LIB","REL":"OR"}], //Arr2
                 [{"ID":"5","NAME":"TIM","DEPT5":"SEC"}]              //Arr3
                }
```

**Code:**

```
let  condArr=[],outArr,i=1;

inArr1.forEach(condt => {
     let dept = Object.keys(condt)[0];
     let tmparr = dept.split("D");
     tmparr.shift()
     condArr.push(tmparr) 
   });

inArr2.forEach(condt => {
    if(condArr.includes(inArr2.D+i)){
        i++;
       outArr.push(inArr2);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bit confused logic, i would suggest rather this

```
let inArr1 = [{"D1D2":"AND"},{"D3D4":"OR"},{"D5D6":"AND"}] 
let inArr2 =[{"ID":"1","NAME":"KEN","DEPT1":"CSE"},
              {"ID":"2","NAME":"MARK","DEPT2":"IT"},
              {"ID":"3","NAME":"TOM","DEPT3":"ECE"},
              {"ID":"4","NAME":"SHIV","DEPT4":"LIB"},
              {"ID":"5","NAME":"TIM","DEPT5":"SEC"},
              {"ID":"6","NAME":"TLA","DEPT6":"SEC"},
            ]

// first lets create object of ids as keys and conditions as values
const [keys, conditions] = inArr1.reduce((agg, cond, index) => {
   Object.entries(cond).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      key.split('D').forEach(v => { if (v) agg[0][v] = { value, index }})   
      agg[1].push([])
   })
   return agg
}, [{}, []]) // {1: "AND", 2: "AND", 3: "OR", 4: "OR"}
conditions.push([])

// and now just map over all elements and add condition if we found id from the keys
inArr2.forEach(item => {
   const cond = keys[item.ID]
   if (cond) conditions[cond.index].push({...item, REL: cond.value}) 
   else conditions[conditions.length - 1].push(item)
})

const res = conditions.filter(v => v.length)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you. Grouping the object mentioned in the relation is not there.

Comment: @MKN, oops, thats right, i changed my answer, please check if it is still actual

Comment: It doesnt work if I add another condition [{"D1D2":"AND"},{"D3D4":"OR"},{"D5D6":"AND"] and adding another object with ID 6 in inarray2

Comment: @MKN, It should, the only problem i see that it shows an empty array in the end, but for this you should change last line to "const res = Object.entries(conditions).filter(v => v[1].length).map(v => v[1])"

Comment: And of course you have an error in your data  [{"D1D2":"AND"},{"D3D4":"OR"},{"D5D6":"AND"], there should be "}" before last square brackets

Comment: Thank you. It does combine based on AND or OR so 1,2,5,6 all are combining into one Array. But I am expecting to combine (1-2)(3-4)(5-6) together.

Comment: @MKN, Actually it is not a service "Do it for Me", it is help for your professional grow...You should try yourself

Comment: Sorry I dint mean in that sense. Actually I am trying myself putting different ways to acheive the functionality but not getting the correct result. Since not an expert in JS so looking for some help in this functionality of the app. It would be very grateful if you could help

Comment: @MKN Your comment touched my heart, i will try =)

Comment: @MKN, check now, please

Answer (score 1):

You could store the goups by using the `ID` and use new objects.

```js
let inArr1 = [{ D1D2: "AND" }, { D3D4: "OR" }],
    inArr2 = [{ ID: "1", NAME: "KEN", DEPT1: "CSE" }, { ID: "2", NAME: "MARK", DEPT2: "IT" }, { ID: "3", NAME: "TOM", DEPT3: "ECE" }, { ID: "4", NAME: "SHIV", DEPT4: "LIB" }, { ID: "5", NAME: "TIM", DEPT5: "SEC" }],
    groups = inArr1.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, REL]) => {
            var object = { REL, group: [] };
            k.match(/[^D]+/g).forEach(id => r[id] = object);
        });        
        return r;
    }, {}),
    grouped = inArr2.reduce((r, o) => {
        var { REL, group } = groups[o.ID] || {};
        if (group) {
            if (!group.length) r.push(group);
            group.push(Object.assign({}, o, { REL }));
        } else {
            r.push([o]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesnt work if you have only D4 is present inArr2 and D3D4 condition is present in the inArr1

Answer (score 0):

can try other solution:

```js
let inArr1 = [{ D1D2: "AND" }, { D3D4: "OR" }, { D6D7: "XOR" }];
let inArr2 = [
  { ID: "1", NAME: "KEN", DEPT1: "CSE" },
  { ID: "2", NAME: "MARK", DEPT2: "IT" },
  { ID: "3", NAME: "TOM", DEPT3: "ECE" },
  { ID: "4", NAME: "SHIV", DEPT4: "LIB" },
  { ID: "5", NAME: "TIM", DEPT5: "SEC" },
  { ID: "9", NAME: "BAR", DEPT5: "XYZ" },
  { ID: "6", NAME: "FOO", DEPT5: "XYZ" },
];

let unmatchedArr = []

let matchedArr = inArr2.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  // getting index matched from inArr1 objects key
  const indexMatched = getIndexMatch(obj.ID);

  // creating index if not exists
  if (!acc[indexMatched] && indexMatched !== null) acc[indexMatched] = [];

  // if some index matched it merge current obj with DEL property with inArr1[indexMatched] key => value
  return indexMatched !== null
    ? acc[indexMatched].push({
      ...obj,
      DEL: inArr1[indexMatched][Object.keys(inArr1[indexMatched])[0]]
    })
    // pushing on unmatchedArr
    : unmatchedArr.push(obj)
    , acc
}, []);

function getIndexMatch(id) {
  for (const [index, obj] of inArr1.entries()) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      // spliting only digits of the current key of object
      if (key.match(/\d/g).includes(id)) return index; // returning index of inArr1 if is included
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// merging arrays
const result = [...matchedArr, unmatchedArr];

console.log(result);
```